# How to get panel appear sliding behind toolbar?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, css-animations, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a top toolbar in my app and on tapping a button/section on toolbar I want to slide out a modal menu panel containing list of menu items but my problem is when I animate to slide it from top it appears to be sliding over toolbar but what I want it to appear like sliding out of bottom edge of toolbar. Here is a [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#gvnpz#35DTe#5sWAv) which shows something what I have done so far.

BTW, I was expecting sliding menu items to be easy to implement but unfortunately I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that line to your toolbar definition:

```
zIndex: 10,
```

And check out `zIndex` config: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.Toolbar-cfg-zIndex

Comment: Ahh that's right, thanks for bringing me back to common sense :)